# Is there a way to override paths defined in *.libraries.yml

Tags: theming, 8

Guess I found a bug here and already filed it:

- Created custom profile,
- added https://www.drupal.org/project/mmenu dependency (which then is placed under `profiles/profile_name/modules/contrib/mmenu`).
- Added MMenu libraries (jquery.mmenu, hammer.js, jquery.hammer),
- activated everything but then Drupal looks for the wrong library paths under `libraries/mmenu` instead of `profiles/profile_name/libraries/mmenu`.

`libraries_get_path('mmenu')` returns correct path `(profiles/profile_name/libraries/mmenu)`.

`drupal_get_profile()` returns correct profile.

Drupal seems to only take the paths defined in `mmenu.libraries.yml` into account. Changing them makes everything work as desired. So, I'm asking myself now: Is there any possibility to override the paths defined in `mmenu.libraries.yml` from a custom module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. [`hook_library_info_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_library_info_alter/8.9.x) is used to alter basically anything in the library definition.

Comment: To expand on that, `libraries_get_path()` is from the Libraries module. It is weird, but it has absolutely nothing to do with libraries.yml files, which are a core feature. To make this work, you need to check the path and dynamically set it for your library definition. Look at jw_player, dropzonejs, and other examples.