# Is it possible to pass variables as arguments to *.libraries.yml?

Tags: 8, javascript

Say I have a foo.libraries.yml defined as so:

```
external.bc.js:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    //players.brightcove.net/{{variable here}}/{{variable here}}/index.min.js: { type: external, minified: true}
```

Where `{{ variable here }}` is where I want to insert values when I attach the library

Then, in a `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view()` I am running:

`$build['#attached']['library'][] = 'brightcove/external.bc.js';`

Which is where I'd also like the pass those variables. Is that possible?

Comment: How dynamic do you need it to be? If it's per environment, for example, you could use [`hook_library_info_build()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_library_info_build/8.8.x) instead of the yml method (it's not possible to pass variables to the yml file to the best of my knowledge)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to override paths defined in \*.libraries.yml](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/210959/is-there-a-way-to-override-paths-defined-in-libraries-yml)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining the library in the .libraries.yml file, you should add it using [`hook_library_info_build()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_library_info_build/8.9.x), which in fact is described using the following sentences.

> Modules may implement this hook to add dynamic library definitions. Static libraries, which do not depend on any runtime information, should be declared in a modulename.libraries.yml file instead.

```php
function mymodule_library_info_build() {
  $libraries = [];

  $js_path = 'the dynamic path to the external JavaScript file';
  $libraries['external.bc.js'] = [
    'version' => '1.x',
    'js' => [
      $js_path => ['type' => 'external', 'minified' => TRUE]
    ],
  ];

  return $libraries;
}
```

If the library has been defined from another module, the hook to use is [`hook_library_info_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_library_info_alter/8.9.x).